# IntelliJ - automatically 'inline' external JAR

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to work on some legacy Java that includes a lot of poorly maintained internal libraries. Checking these out and maintaining them is a huge pain, and our technical direction is to deprecate JARs that are shared between projects.

Given I have both src and test src JARs for these libraries, does IntelliJ have a magic way of bringing the source .java directly into the project, so it no longer lives externally?

Comment: Interesting question. This doesn't answer your question directly, but you could definitely script this. A jar file is just a zip file.

Comment: Yeah, scripting is definitely an option. I'd just rather not reinvent the wheel if such functionality already exists :)

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? Given that the library is used in more than one place, you are now effectively copy-pasting the same code into different places, instead of maintaining a library with releases. As they say in Sparta, this is madness! A maintenance nightmare. Google the software engineering principle named DRY.

Comment: There is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @vikingsteve - the overall system architecture has changed and these libraries are no longer shared; they are essentially in use only in this one project.

Comment: If you realy need to copy paste code then doing an actual copy paste from the test-sources jar might be easiest...